# How to provide 'Search as you type' in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportparameter

Is there a way I can provide my user 'Search as you type' functionality in my SSRS reports filters, I have multiple valued string parameters, they convert to checked listboxes in report manager, and user have to find and select one by one. This is a tedious work if there are hundreds of records in filter.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not come out of the box with SSRS. You can extend SSRS using the ReportExecution2008 web services and gain a lower level of granularity.